# How to extract numbers from string but keep decimals?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract numbers from string using

`cat out.log | tr -dc '0-9'`

In Bash but I want to keep the decimals but this script will only keep numbers and no decimals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883661/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: This is not what i want as it also deletes decimals

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.` and likely a space to the character class like so:

```
$ echo "12.32foo 44.2 bar" | tr -dc '[. [:digit:]]'
12.32 44.2
```

Comment: Note that this also keeps lone periods, i.e. from `echo oh.my.god|tr  -dc '[. [:digit:]]'`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+([.][[:digit:]]+)?' <out.log
```

`-o` takes care that only the parts matching the pattern are written to stdout. The pattern greedily matches one or more digits, followed by optionally a decimal point and more digits. Note that this on purpose skips "numbers" such as `.56` and `14.`, since they are considered malformed. If you want to include them, you can easily adjust the pattern to this.

Comment: Works well with input `echo "Number 1 is odd. Number 2 is even. Just like 4. And 3.45 is a fractal.`