# extract number from string and do math operation with bash

Tags: bash

What's proper way to extract number from a string and do math on it?
e.g.

```
var="VmRSS: 181420 kB"
out=(numbers in $var)/1024 # expected 181420/1024 = 177.168 MB
```

Comment: What did you try? -[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883661/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: Note that the shell itself only does integer division, not floating-point.

Comment: `[[ $var =~ ^[^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+).*$ ]] && echo "scale=2; ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} / 1024" | bc`